# Getting distinct data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

At the moment I'm on the process of getting the counts of the unique email address in the database .

```
Table1
---------------------------------------------
 id    email          name      date_applied
---------------------------------------------
 1    abc@mail.com   ABC       2013-04-17
 2    bcd@mail.com   BCD       2013-04-18
 3    xyz@mail.com   XYZ       2013-04-20
 4    tre@mail.com   TRE       2013-04-28
 5    esf@mail.com   ESF       2013-04-29
 6    bcd@mail.com   BCD       2013-04-29
 7    abc@mail.com   ABC       2013-04-30
---------------------------------------------
```

Here's the query on how I get the unique emails for the week:

```
select count(distinct(`A`.`email`)) as total 
from Table1 as A 
where A.date_applied BETWEEN `2013-04-29` and `2013-05-05`

Current Week: 2013-04-29 => 2013-05-05
```

What I wanted to achieve is to get the count of the new emails in the current week without ignoring the emails in the previous weeks.

I badly needed your help.

Comment: If you remove `distinct` from your query don't you get the count of new emails this week?

Comment: What is your desired output from the current table data?

Comment: It will give me the count of the emails for the week but `Id 7` in the table is not unique.

Comment: @hims056 I want to output `total count: 2` since I will the data from `2013-04-29` to `2013-05-05` and `abc@mail.com` is not unique.

Comment: @jtanix - `bcd@mail.com` is also not unique. Right?

Comment: @jtanix bcd@mail.com is also not unique

Comment: sorry the output must be `total: 1` the ` bcd@mail.com` had also duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to aggregate. To get the date a distinct email was added:

```
SELECT email, MIN(date_applied) as first
FROM Table1
GROUP BY email
HAVING first BETWEEN 2013-04-29 AND 2013-05-05
```

The number of rows in your result is your answer.

Or use a sub query. I still have to get used to MySQL supporting them. :)

You should think about your schema design, though. I understand this is probably a minimal example, but `date_applied` is not really the applicationdate in your mindmap. In your mind `email` is KEY in this table, not `Id`. Why not have the dbschema congrue with your mind? Then your query will be simpler, and more performant.

Comment: thanks I realize now. I deal with a lot of data and I need to consider also the load time. These query is efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using sub-query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `email`) AS Total FROM Table1 AS A 
  WHERE A.date_applied 
BETWEEN '2013-04-29' AND '2013-05-05'
    AND A.email NOT IN (SELECT email FROM Table1
                         WHERE date_applied < '2013-04-29');
```

Result:

```
| TOTAL |
---------
|     1 |
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a3c58/12)

---

Here is the description of the query:

First of all you need to get email between two dates (i.e. a week) like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT email FROM Table1
 WHERE date_applied BETWEEN '2013-04-29' AND '2013-05-05'
```

Then search for emails which are not unique (i.e. already exists on previous date):

```
SELECT email 
  FROM Table1
 WHERE date_applied < '2013-04-29'
```

Now exclude those emails from our current query by using `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `email` FROM Table1 AS A 
  WHERE A.date_applied 
BETWEEN '2013-04-29' AND '2013-05-05'
    AND A.email NOT IN (SELECT email FROM Table1
                         WHERE date_applied < '2013-04-29');
```

Now use `COUNT()` function to get the count of emails.

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a3c58/16)

Comment: @jtanix - Glad to help you. See my update for query description. :)

Comment: one thing I observe since I have a thousands of data. It takes a lot of time for it to query the result. Is this normal?

Comment: @jtanix - Since we have to use sub-query it takes more time than normal query.